# Problemas instalación Pentaho

Tags: java-8, pentaho

Voy a usar **Pentaho** por primera vez, en un proyecto de la universidad, para hacer minería de datos. El programa **no funciona en mi maquina**.

Mensaje que aparece al intentar acceder al servidor:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: No se puede compilar la clase para
> JSP:
>
> Estado HTTP 500 -

```
type Informe de Excepción

mensaje

descripción El servidor encontró un error interno () que hizo que no pudiera rellenar este requerimiento.

excepción

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: No se puede compilar la clase para JSP: 

Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: 1 en el fichero java generado
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: 82 en el archivo jsp: /jsp/PUCLogin.jsp
The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
79:     <%
80:       String ua = request.getHeader("User-Agent").toLowerCase();
81:       if (!"desktop".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getParameter("mode"))) {        
82:         if (ua.contains("ipad") || ua.contains("ipod") || ua.contains("iphone") || ua.contains("android") || "mobile".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getParameter("mode"))) {        
83:           IPluginManager pluginManager = PentahoSystem.get(IPluginManager.class, PentahoHttpSessionHelper.getPentahoSession(request)); 
84:           List<String> pluginIds = pluginManager.getRegisteredPlugins();
85:           for (String id : pluginIds) {


Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: 82 en el archivo jsp: /jsp/PUCLogin.jsp
The method contains(CharSequence) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String)
79:     <%
80:       String ua = request.getHeader("User-Agent").toLowerCase();
81:       if (!"desktop".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getParameter("mode"))) {        
82:         if (ua.contains("ipad") || ua.contains("ipod") || ua.contains("iphone") || ua.contains("android") || "mobile".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getParameter("mode"))) {        
83:           IPluginManager pluginManager = PentahoSystem.get(IPluginManager.class, PentahoHttpSessionHelper.getPentahoSession(request)); 
84:           List<String> pluginIds = pluginManager.getRegisteredPlugins();
85:           for (String id : pluginIds) {


Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: 82 en el archivo jsp: /jsp/PUCLogin.jsp
The method contains(CharSequence) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String)
79:     <%
80:       String ua = request.getHeader("User-Agent").toLowerCase();
81:       if (!"desktop".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getParameter("mode"))) {        
82:         if (ua.contains("ipad") || ua.contains("ipod") || ua.contains("iphone") || ua.contains("android") || "mobile".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getParameter("mode"))) {        
83:           IPluginManager pluginManager = PentahoSystem.get(IPluginManager.class, PentahoHttpSessionHelper.getPentahoSession(request)); 
84:           List<String> pluginIds = pluginManager.getRegisteredPlugins();
85:           for (String id : pluginIds) {


Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: 82 en el archivo jsp: /jsp/PUCLogin.jsp
The method contains(CharSequence) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String)
79:     <%
80:       String ua = request.getHeader("User-Agent").toLowerCase();
81:       if (!"desktop".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getParameter("mode"))) {        
82:         if (ua.contains("ipad") || ua.contains("ipod") || ua.contains("iphone") || ua.contains("android") || "mobile".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getParameter("mode"))) {        
83:           IPluginManager pluginManager = PentahoSystem.get(IPluginManager.class, PentahoHttpSessionHelper.getPentahoSession(request)); 
84:           List<String> pluginIds = pluginManager.getRegisteredPlugins();
85:           for (String id : pluginIds) {


Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: 82 en el archivo jsp: /jsp/PUCLogin.jsp
The method contains(CharSequence) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String)
79:     <%
80:       String ua = request.getHeader("User-Agent").toLowerCase();
81:       if (!"desktop".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getParameter("mode"))) {        
82:         if (ua.contains("ipad") || ua.contains("ipod") || ua.contains("iphone") || ua.contains("android") || "mobile".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getParameter("mode"))) {        
83:           IPluginManager pluginManager = PentahoSystem.get(IPluginManager.class, PentahoHttpSessionHelper.getPentahoSession(request)); 
84:           List<String> pluginIds = pluginManager.getRegisteredPlugins();
85:           for (String id : pluginIds) {


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:314)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.PentahoWebContextFilter.doFilter(PentahoWebContextFilter.java:142)
    org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.PentahoRequestContextFilter.doFilter(PentahoRequestContextFilter.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.pentaho.platform.web.http.security.SecurityStartupFilter.doFilter(SecurityStartupFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.pentaho.platform.web.http.security.RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.java:169)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:278)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.pentaho.platform.web.http.security.HttpSessionReuseDetectionFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionReuseDetectionFilter.java:134)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:99)
    org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.SystemStatusFilter.doFilter(SystemStatusFilter.java:60)
    org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:113)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿cómo puedo resolver este problema?

> ***Información adicional:***
>
> Ya he creado la variable de entorno para usar Pentaho y para el SDK de Java
>
> SO **Windows 7**
>
> Pentaho comunity
>
> **Java SDK 8**

Comment: Te damos la Bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español. Te invito a que pases por el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leas el artículo [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida. Por favor, comparte el código donde se produce el error

Comment: Hola buenas tarder desarrolla mejor tu pregunta explicando un poco mas tu problema